# Closure operators and complete lattices.

Tags: category-theory, lattice-orders, adjoint-functors

A *closure operator* on a set $A$ is a function $C: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ satisfying following axioms:

- $X ⊆ Y \implies C(X) ⊆ C(Y)$
- $X ⊆ C(X)$

It may also satisfy some additional axioms:

- $C(C(X)) = C(X)$
- $C(∅) = ∅$
- $C(\{x\}) = \{x\}$ for all $x ∈ A$

We call a set $X ⊆ A$ closed (with respect to $C$) if $C(X) = X$. To every closure operator $C$ we may assign the set of all closed sets $F(C)$, which is a complete lattice. 
On the other hand to every complete lattice $L$ we can assign closure operator $G(L)$ on the set of all atoms $At(L)$: $G(L)(X) := \{x ∈ At(L): x ≤ \bigvee X\}$.

$F$ and $G$ gives natural correspondence between closure operators satisfying the additional axioms and atomistic complete lattices: $G(F(C)) \cong C$ and $F(G(L)) \cong L$. (A lattice is atomistic if every element is a join of atoms.)

My question is following:

> Can this natural correspondence be extended? Is there a bigger class of complete lattices and $G'$ which maps such lattice to a closure operator such that $F$, $G'$ form a correspondence exteding $F$, $G$?

Comment: Your definition of $G(L)(X)$ can be extended from atomistic lattices to complete lattices in general, by making $G(L)(X) = \{ x \in L : x \leq \bigvee X \}$ (see, for example, Burris & Sankappanavar, Ch.I, Th.5.3, available from https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf).

Comment: @amrsa: But then we lose $G(F(C)) \cong C$ even for topological spaces.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. It seems to me that in your notation $G(F(C))$ is the set (the lattice) of closed sets of the closure operator that you defined on the atoms of $C$. In the definition I presented, $G(L(C))$ is the set of closed sets of the closure operator defined on the powerset of $C$. In these conditions, the theorem I mentioned in the previous comment (or its proof anyway...) asserts that $C \cong G(F(C))$, provided $C$ is complete, which includes many non-atomistic lattices.

Comment: @amrsa $C$ cannot be complete as it is not a lattice but a closure operator/space. The theorem says $L \cong F(G(L))$ for a complete lattice $L$, but not $C \cong G(F(C))$ for (even a topological) closure space $C$. So it generalizes the correspondence on one side but specializes on the other.

Comment: Yeah, so it means I misunderstood you and got twisted with your notation.